# Triangular commutative diagram

Tags: diagrams, xy-pic

I am using the `\xymatrix` command

this is the code I've written

```
\[\xymatrix{
& A \ar[d]^{i}\\
 B \ar@{-->}[ru]^-{\exists \overset{\sim} \varphi}\ar[r]^{\varphi}&C
}\]
```

My problem is with the `[ru]...` The dashed arrow goes upward, whereas I want it to go downward; and I keep getting an error !

Comment: Can you provide a MWE? Which packages have you included? Are you in a point where the `@` symbol is a letter?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/5001)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use `\ar@{<--}`, but it's conceptually better to originate it from `A`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}

\begin{document}

\[
\xymatrix{
  & A \ar[d]^{i} \ar@{-->}[dl]_-{\exists \tilde{\varphi}} \\
  B \ar[r]^{\varphi} &C
}
\]

\end{document}
```

Note `\tilde{\varphi}`, rather than `\overset{\sim}{\varphi}`. You can use `\widetilde` if the accent seems too short.

[image]

Alternatively, you can use `tikz-cd`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}
  {} & A \arrow{d}{i} \arrow[dashed,swap]{dl}{\exists \tilde{\varphi}} \\
  B \arrow{r}{\varphi} & C
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]